# Redirect /members/ to /project/members/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In the production version of my code, the folder 'members' is in the root of the production server. The links in the members folder are formatted like `/members/`.

In the development version of my code, the folder 'project' is in the root of the development server since there are multiple projects on that server. The links in the members folder are formatted like `/project/members/`.

I don't want to change my links manually e.g. every time I upload a new build. How do I redirect `/members/` to `/project/members/` in .htaccess?

`Redirect /members/ /project/members/` did not work since it did not change it's subdomains.

Comment: What do you mean by `it did not change it's subdomains`?

Comment: Well, `/members/add_user/` still does not go to `/project/members/add_user/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/members/.*)$ /project/$1
```

**For JS/CSS issue:**

For css/js etc use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with http:// or a slash /.

Or else you can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: The line of code you provided doesn't work for my style sheets. However, you saying it should be in the DocumentRoot instead of the project's folder did help out with the line I already had. Thanks!

Comment: For css/js etc use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. ELSE You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with half of anubhava's. The .htaccess file should be in the root of the web folder and not in the project folder. Moving the file it works with the next line.

```
Redirect /members/ /project/members/
```